# Floated div that fills remaining width of parent

Tags: html, css

How can I have foo fill the remainder of the container's width if there is at least 50px remaining. If foo is > 50px it moves to a new line increasing the container's height. This question [HTML/CSS: Expanding a float-left element to remaining width of parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713573/html-css-expanding-a-float-left-element-to-remaining-width-of-parent) is the same. I refuse to believe this can't be done without javascript. Come at me bro.

```
.container {
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 30px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.child {
  float: left
}
.foo {
  /* ? */
}
```

Comment: Who downvoted me!? Come at me bro!

Comment: You want foo to fill container if there is >= 50px remaining. What happens when there isn't, go to next line? btw - no way this is possible CSS only. CSS doesn't do if statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fiddled something for you: http://jsfiddle.net/mac_cain13/K5fJP

The .foo div has a `min-width` to make sure it will go to the next line there is less then 50px available. The `overflow: hidden;` makes sure the div is not behind the .child div.

I added some JavaScript to demo the behavior when .child gets wider. Click the .child div to add some pixels to it's width. When the .child div takes so much space that there is less then 50px left the .foo div will jump to the next line.

Pure CSS, but only tested in Safari. :)

Answer (score 1):

There are CSS hacks available when you know the width of the others. Or you could just use a table. But there is no concept in CSS such as "width: 100% - otherelement.width", this only works in JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

Check this out

It's working now

http://jsfiddle.net/mikulgohil/fdVws/

HTML code:

```
<div class="container"> <div class="child">First</div> <div class="foo">Second</div> </div>
```

CSS code:

```
.container {
  width: 300px;

  overflow: auto;
    background:#ff00dd;
}
.child {
  float: left;
    background:#ff0;
}
.foo {
  background:#0033dd;
}
```

Comment: Thats not what you want, remove the background-color from the .child div and you see the .foo div is actually behind the .child div.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mikulgohil/fdVws/1/   check now but u will not get 100% width of .foo div

Comment: That does not really work. If you make the second div longer it wraps around the first instead of floating to the right:

`<div class="container"> <div class="child">First</div> <div class="foo">Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second </div> </div> ​`