# How to give automatic width to divs inside outer div?

Tags: html, css

[image]I have divs

```
<div id='top' >
    <div id='top-border' > </div>
    <div id='top-menu' > <jdoc:include type="modules" name="top-menu" style="well" /></div>
</div>
```

and style

```
#top {
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#top-border {
    background: url(../images/border.png) repeat-x scroll 0px 18px;
    position: relative;
    /*width:74%;*/
    height:40px;
    float:left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#top-menu {
    margin:0;
    float:right;
    height:40px;
    padding-top:6px;
}
```

What I want to put content in top-menu so it will shrink automatically depending to its content. The rest width will be given to top-border which has background image. 
When I give width to top-border it works fine. But I want flexible width not fixed.
Any idea?

Comment: you can use table format for that structure

Comment: Is it possible with div? I do not want to use div and table at the same time.

Comment: then u have to use jquery because atleast one div have fixed with using css

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284803/floated-div-that-fills-remaining-width-of-parent

Comment: even if one div has a fixed with you can use this [link](http://css-tricks.com/the-perfect-fluid-width-layout/) to get what you want but not both dynamic is possible

Comment: I see, two dynamic is not possible. So I should find another way to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use table(width:100%) instead of outer div. Replace top-border and top-menu use td.
For top-border td use css "width: 1px; white-space: nowrap;"

Comment: After all, If you wish to use div, you can give top-border's width using javascript. document.getElementById("top-border").style.width = document.getElementById("top").offsetWidth - document.getElementById("top-menu").offsetMenu + "px"; This should be call on/after onload.

Comment: So as I understood, it is not possible without using javascript?

Comment: Maybe using html5's flex layout or grid layout. But old browsers wont support it.

Comment: Everything is complicated, I will try to find out some decisions without using jQuery

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `word-wrap` CSS Property along with the `width` and you will get what you want.

Here is the [Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/VAaxe/1/).

**The HTML:**

```
<div id="top">
    <div id="top-border">abc</div>
    <div id="op-menu"> <jdoc:include type="modules" name="top-menu" style="well" />def</div>
</div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
#top {
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#top-border {
    background: url(../images/border.png) repeat-x scroll 0px 18px red;
    position: relative;
    /*width:74%;*/
    height:40px;
    float:left;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 20px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
#top-menu {
    margin:0;
    float:right;
    height:40px;
    padding-top:6px;
}
```

I hope this Helps.

**EDIT**

If the width has to be dynamic. Here is the [Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/VAaxe/2/).

**The HTML:**

```
<div id="top">
    <div id="top-border">The Quick Brown Fox jumps Over The Lazy Dog. The Quick Brown Fox jumps Over The Lazy Dog. The Quick Brown Fox jumps Over The Lazy Dog. The Quick Brown Fox jumps Over The Lazy Dog. The Quick Brown Fox jumps Over The Lazy Dog. </div>
    <div id="op-menu"> <jdoc:include type="modules" name="top-menu" style="well" />def</div>
</div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
#top {
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#top-border {
    background: url(../images/border.png) repeat-x scroll 0px 18px red;
    position: relative;
    /*width:74%;*/
    height:40px;
    float:left;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 97%;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
#top-menu {
    margin:0;
    float:right;
    height:40px;
    padding-top:6px;
}
```

I hope this helps now.

**EDIT - 2**

Here is the [Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/VAaxe/4/) without defining any width and moving the box independently on the basis of content it has.

**The HTML:**

```
<div id="top">
    <div id="top-border">The Quick Brown Fox jumps Over The Lazy Dog. The Quick Brown Fox jumps Over The Lazy Dog. The Quick Brown Fox jumps Over The Lazy Dog. The Quick Brown Fox jumps Over The Lazy Dog. The Quick Brown Fox jumps Over The Lazy Dog. </div>
    <div id="top-menu"> <jdoc:include type="modules" name="top-menu" style="well" />def</div>
</div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
#top {
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display:table-row;
}
#top-border {
    background: url(../images/border.png) repeat-x scroll 0px 18px red;
    position: relative;
    /*width:74%;*/
    height:40px;

    display:table-cell;
}
#top-menu {
    margin:0;
    height:40px;
    padding-top:6px;
    background:green;
    display:table-cell;
}
```

Hope THIS Helps Now.

Comment: I have just put the width to 20px; but it is just for understanding. You can your own width and use it along with word-wrap property to wrap the text in the div and work it as per what your purpose is. - @FirdavsKurbonov

Comment: Ok I have updated my answer as EDIT. You can have a look - Hope this helps now. @FirdavsKurbonov

Comment: This is my last update for you. http://jsfiddle.net/VAaxe/3/ Let me know is that what you want? - @FirdavsKurbonov

Comment: No, this is not what I want. You are giving     width: 90%; Read my question, if I give width exactly it works. But I want to give them dynamic width depending what is inside second div. If second div width will be 20% so div1 will be 80% or viceversa.

Comment: Aah.. Sorry.. I got your point. Find the soltion in EDIT - 2  in my answer above. Hope this helps now. - @FirdavsKurbonov

Comment: No it is not showing top-border background and top menu floated to left

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30310/discussion-between-nathan-lee-and-firdavs-kurbonov)

Comment: Send me a screenshot of how you want - @FirdavsKurbonov

Comment: Please go to CSS problem room in chat

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand the question correctly, but it seems to me that the `top-border` div is redundant. Don't use elements purely for presentational hooks. You could either set a top border to the `top-menu` div or padding-top and a background image. As you've already seen, floating the top-menu makes it only as wide as its content. The same would happen with `display: inline-block;` or `display: table`.

EDIT: O, sorry, I see what you are asking now. Here's one simple way you can do that without an image (though you can use an image too): http://codepen.io/pageaffairs/pen/ECFny

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">
body {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

#top {
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #f7f7f7;
}

#top ul {
    margin:0;
    list-style: none;
    float:right;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
}

#top li {
    margin: 0 0 0 20px;
    float: left;
}

#top li a {
    display: block;
    line-height: 40px;
}

#top ul:before {
    content:" ";
    height: 0;
    width:999em;
    right:100%;
    border-top: 2px dashed #000;
    position:absolute;
    top:19px;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>

<div id='top'>
    <ul> 
        <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Would be happy to, but please first show us your full attempt at this, with the image(s), so it's clear what you want to do (I'm not totally sure I understand your question). Can you provide a link, or an example on JSFiddle?

Comment: added image, check question

Comment: That image is too small to decipher, and an image is no use, anyhow. I really don't get what you are asking.

Comment: EDIT: Ah, sorry, now I get what you are asking for. Above is an example of you you can do that, though there are other ways, too. http://codepen.io/pageaffairs/pen/ECFny

Comment: The image is not dash, it is one dash one point something like this. So clients wants to use image.

Comment: The problem is that this is Joomla template, not html. So I will try to use your code in my joomla template and come back with answer. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: The dashed line was just an example. You can use an image instead. I just don't have your image to use.

Answer (score 0):

you can't display a div only with background image until you specify some width for that element or put some contents in it.

So to display #top-border div you must need to filled it with some content or give some width.